# Hover text to show total rep score in the "Users" display

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

When I hover my mouse over the UserName against a Comment, that user's current rep value is displayed.

Would it be possible to replicate this behaviour in the "Users" display? And do I need to make out a specific case for this request, or should it simply be decided on the basis of how many people upvote this question, and/or how technically difficult it is to implement?

Comment: To which "Users" display are you referring?

Comment: I didn't know there was more than one. I mean the one you get when you pick the third option out of *Questions / Tags / Users / Badges / Unanswered / Ask Question*, where you only see "total current rep" if you select "All" out of *Week / Month / Quarter / Year / All*. Sometimes I would like to see the "All" value for a given User without having to refresh the whole display from a different time-frame.

Comment: As you noticed, the "week," "month," "quarter," "year," and "all" pages are different pages. The only one that is already showing the total reputation is the last one.

Comment: Obviously I know that. Is my request still not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a tooltip when you hover on the reputation number in the user list.

Will be deployed in the next day or so.

Comment: Awesome! To be honest, I'd have been bowled over if someone had actually confirmed they understood what I *meant* (or upvoted the request, which may amount to the same thing). No disrespect to Jim, but how come *four* people think [this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2372) change is worth your time? Anyway, thanks - and for your next trick, how about [this one](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1800)?